# extracting stream from pdf in python

Tags: python, pdf, stream, reportlab, pypdf

How can I extract the part of this stream (the one named BLABLABLA) from the pdf file which contains it??

```
<</Contents 583 0 R/CropBox[0 0 595.22 842]/MediaBox[0 0 595.22 842]/Parent 29 0  /Resources<</ColorSpace<</CS0 563 0 R>>/ExtGState<</GS0 568 0 R>>/Font<</TT0 559 0 R/TT1 560 0 R/TT2 561 0 R/TT3 562 0 R>>/ProcSet[/PDF/Text/ImageC]/Properties<</MC0<</BLABLABLA 584 0 R>>/MC1<</SubKey 582 0 R>>>>/XObject<</Im0 578 0 R>>>>/Rotate 0/StructParents 0/Type/Page>>
```

Or, in other worlds, how can I extract a subkey from a pdf stream?

I would like to use some python's library (like pyPdf or ReportLab), but even some C/C++ lib should go well for me.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: I haven't use this myself, but maybe [the gfx module in swftool](http://www.swftools.org/gfx_tutorial.html) can help you.

Comment: Google code has a python text-extraction tool called [pdf miner](http://code.google.com/p/pdfminerr/source/browse/trunk/pdfminer). I don't know if it will do what you want, but it might be worth a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, a stream in a PDF is just a sequence of binary data.  I think you are wanting to extract part of an object.  Are you wanting a standard object, like an image or text?  It would be a lot easier to give you example code if there was a real example.

This might help get you started:

```
import pyPdf
pdf = pyPdf.PdfFileReader(open("pdffile.pdf"))
list(pdf.pages) # Process all the objects.
print pdf.resolvedObjects
```

Comment: Is it possible to extract whole object by number? I am trying to extract objects with malicious code for automated analyzing.